# Form with multiple input fields that has an responsible Person per field

Tags: forms, input, web

I am trying to design a web based input form for a database. For my form, I have two users groups. Both of which need to be able to edit every field. But one of the two groups is always responsible for the field. And it needs to be visible who is responsible.

How do I design the form in a way that is not overloading the user with labels while still having it visible, which group is responsible for a specific field?

**Example**:

Field A -- Can be edited by both groups but Group 1 is responsible

Field B -- Can be edited by both groups but Group 2 is responsible

Field C -- Can be edited by both groups but Group 1 is responsible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the order of the fields important?

If not, visually group them on the form:

```
GROUP 1:
- Field A
- Field D
- …

GROUP 2:
- Field B
- Field C
- …
```

Or, assuming the group of the person doing the editing is known, the form could visually mark the other group's fields (e.g. fainter colour, smaller font, italic font).

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is an easy solution that didnt come into my mind. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is an easy solution that didnt come into my mind. Thank you

Comment: @fabiux, normally one shouldn't mark an answer as accepted so soon. Personally I wait 24 hours to give people in all time zones a chance to see the question. It's possible that someone could have a better answer, but they'll see that this already has an accepted answer and not bother even reading your question. If someone *does* give a better answer though, feel free to move the check-mark to theirs. (But you could also up-vote mine, or others.)